# Headless SXA - Ensuring links are localized

Tags: multilingual, graphql, nextjs, sxa-jss

We're developing a `Language Switcher` for our `SXA NextJS` app, I followed the documentation from NextJS on how to perform the switch and it works (switching from language A to language B) but what I noticed was the links from our menu still points to the default language set for the site. We built our menu to retrieve the pages via `GraphQL` and part of that query is to use the page item's `path` property

```
search(where: ...)
{ 
   total
   results { 
     id
     url {
       path #This just returns /Item-Name
     }
   } 
}
```

What happens now is that our links don't have the language code (`/Item-Name` instead of `/jp-JP/Item-Name`) on the URL.

As a fix, I updated the GraphQL to use the `url` property instead and create a `new URL()` object with it then retrieve the `.pathname` property. Is this the right approach, or is there a cleaner way of making our menu to support multi-language?